# Initialising child entity in one-to-many relationship causes duplicate

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework

I came across that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726480/nullreferenceexception-when-trying-to-add-in-one-to-many-relation). My problem quite similar.

I've two EF classes Appointment and Job. Has one to many relationship among them.

```
 public class Appointment
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentStatus { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Job {get; set; }

}
 public class Job
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public short JobMode { get; set; }
    public virtual Appointment Appointments { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to add a job to instance of Appointment, I am getting nullreferenceexception. Because of Appointment's Job property returning null. It's normal so far.

For handling that exception, I've tried to add a block to Parent's constraction for initalize new Job item when Appointment Created.

```
       public Appointment()
    {
        if (this.Job == null)
        {
            this.Job = new Collection<Job>();
        }
    }
```

In that time, I am not getting nullreferenceexception anymore, but that solution causes duplicate Job item. New appointment successfully created but(!), not my selected job. Actually an instance of my selected Job. Each time a new instance of job creating and associating with newly created Appointment.

[image: example job]

Comment: Initializing Appointment with an empty ICollection<Job> is the right thing to do.  Please update your question with the code that "causes duplicate Job item".

Comment: Voting to close for lacking an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice to stick to the [Entity Framework Code-First conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx). It makes life easier for you and for those who read your code in future.

In your case this means that every `Appointment` has zero or more `Jobs`, and every `Job` belongs to exactly one `Appointment` using foreign key.

```
class Appointment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Appointment has zero or more Jobs:
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs {get; set;}

    ...
}

class Job
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Job belongs to exactly one Appointment using foreign key:
    public int AppointmentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Appointment Appointment {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

Because I stuck to the conventions, entity framework is able to detect the one-to-many relationship. It detects the primary keys and foreign keys: no need for attributes nor fluent API.

> In Entity Framework columns in your table are non-virtual properties
>   in your classes. Relations between tables (one-to-many, many-to-many,
>   ...) are marked virtual: they are not real items in your table

It's just an advice, if you have good reasons to deviate from the conventions, you can of course do that.

However, it is obliged to define the relations between tables as virtual. You also need to define the foreign key.

Once you've done that, your fetched Appointments won't have a null Jobs:

```
var fetchedAppointment = dbContext.Appointments
    .Where(appointment => appointment.Id = ...)
    .FirstOrDefault();
// fetchedAppointment.Jobs is not null!

// add a new Job:
fetchedAppointment.Jobs.Add(new Job()
{
     // no need to fill the Id, nor the foreign key. Entity Framework will do that for you
     JobName = ...,
     JobDescription = ...,
     ...
});
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, if you want to add a new Appointment with one or more Jobs, you'll have to add them yourselves. You can use an array or a list, doesn't matter, as long as it implements `ICollection<Job>`

```
var addedAppointment = dbContext.Appointments.Add(new Appointment()
{
    // no need to fill the Id: entity framework will do that for you
    AppointmentStatus = ...
    Remarks = ...

    Jobs = new List<Job>()
    {
         // again: no need to fill the Id, nor the foreign key.
         // Entity Framework will do that for you
         new Job()
         {
             JobName = ...,
             JobDescription = ...,
         },
         new Job()
         {
             JobName = ...,
             JobDescription = ...,
         },
         ...
    },
});

// if you want, you can also add a Job here:
addedAppointment.Jobs.Add(new Job()
{
    JobName = ...,
    JobDescription = ...,
});

// All primary and foreign keys will be filled as soon as you call SaveChanges
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Of course you can also add a Job to the context with an appointment that it belongs to:

```
var addedJob = dbContext.Jobs.Add(new Job()
{
    JobName = ...,
    JobDescription = ...,

    // this Job is a job of addedAppointment
    Appointment = addedAppointment,
}
```

Or if you already Saved the appointment, so primary key has a value:

```
var addedJob = dbContext.Jobs.Add(new Job()
{
    JobName = ...,
    JobDescription = ...,

    // fill the foreign key instead
    AppointmentId = addedAppointment.Id
},
```